# ZK: How to intercept/use an event from a parent menubar?

Tags: java, ajax, menu, listener, zk

I just started to learn ZK, and I'm having a seriuos problem to intercept an event (onClick) from a parent menubar that contain several menu and menuitem.

I'm using AJAX to change the src uri of a internal panel.

I don't want to create a unique class for each menuitem.

I want to (but I don't know if and how is possible) to create a class to intercept onClick event from menubar, BUT when such event appear, in fact, on a menuitem.

So I want to tie the class controller to menubar, but, at the same time, get the menuitem that the user click on.

Here my code:

Index.zul

```
<zk>
<style>.z-menubar-hor, .z-menubar-ver { border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; }
.content {overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll;}</style>

        <borderlayout hflex="1" vflex="1" id="mainBorder">
            <north>
                <include src="topBanner.zul"/>
            </north>
            <west>
                <panel hflex="1" vflex="1" border="normal" title="MENU COMANDI" apply="mainPage.MenuAjaxbasedController">
                    <panelchildren style="padding:5px;">
                        <menubar id="menubar" orient="vertical" autodrop="true">
                            <menu label="ANAGRAFICA" id="anagrafica">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="contatti" label="CONTATTI" />
                                    <menuitem id="listeDiDistribuzione" label="LISTE DISTRIBUZIONE" />
                                    <menuitem id="sottoscrizioni" label="SOTTOSCRIZIONI" />
                                    <menuitem id="profilo" label="PROFILO" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                            <menu label="MESSAGGI">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="nuovaNewsletter" label="NUOVA NEWSLETTER" />
                                    <menuitem id="messaggiInviati" label="MESSAGGI INVIATI" />
                                    <menuitem id="bozze" label="BOZZE" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                            <menu label="STRUMENTI">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="smtpServers" label="SMTP SERVERS" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                        </menubar>
                    </panelchildren>
                </panel>
            </west>
            <center id="mainContent" autoscroll="true" border="none">
                <include id="mainContentInclude" self="@define(content)" src=""/>
            </center>
            <south>
                <include src="bottomFooter.zul"/>
            </south>
        </borderlayout>
```

MenuAjaxBasedController.java

```
public class MenuAjaxbasedController extends SelectorComposer<Component>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Wire
Center mainContent;

@Wire
Borderlayout mainBorder;

@Wire
Menuitem contatti;

@Wire
Include mainContentInclude;

@Wire
Menubar menubar;

@Listen("onClick = #contatti")
public void change_page(Event e){
    // Menubar mb = (Menubar) e.getTarget();
    System.out.println(e.getTarget());
    String locationUri = "anagraficaContattiMainGrid.zul";
    // alert("menu link test");
    Include include = (Include)Selectors.iterable(mainBorder.getPage(), "#mainContentInclude").iterator().next();
    include.setSrc(locationUri);
}

}
```

As you can see, I'm only listening a single menuitem now.

Thanks very much and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways come to mind..

### Using ZK Bindings

Using [ZK's `@Listen` approach](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Forwarding), you can listen for more than one event with a single listener by separating events with a semi-colon (`;`).
For example:

```
@Listen("onClick = #contatti; onClick = #listeDiDistribuzione; onClick = #sottoscrizioni")
public void changePage(Event event) {
    event.getTarget(); // the specific button clicked
}
```

This can be cleaned up when you note that [these are just CSS selectors](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC#The_jQuery.2FCSS3-like_Component_Selector):

```
@Listen("onClick = #menubar ~ menuitem")
public void changePage(Event event) {
    event.getTarget(); // the specific button clicked
}
```

There are *many many* possibilities here, read the documentation (linked above) and you'll come up with something good.

### Swing Style

The other way to approach this is to do so from the Java side. This is very Swing-ish and not as cleanly separated between the view, but totally valid and worth mentioning.

```
private static final EventListener<Event> LISTENER = new EventListener<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        event.getTarget(); // the specific button clicked
    }
}

@Wire
private Menuitem contatti;
@Wire
private Menuitem listeDiDistribuzione;

@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component component) {
    contatti.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, LISTENER);
    listeDiDistribuzione.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, LISTENER);
}
```

Of course, here you can simplify things with some CSS selecting also..

```
@Wire("#menubar ~ menuitem")
private List<Menuitem> menuitems;

@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component component) {
    for (Menuitem menuitem : menuitems) {
        menuitem.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, LISTENER);
    }
}
```

Benvenuto in StackOverflow.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for the super answer :) The only problem, I can't make @Listen("onClick = #menubar ~ menuitem") to work... it simply does nothing to me, but I see it's recognized as a command... Thanks also for the greetings :)

Comment: I've never used the tilde (`~`) selector myself, `@Listen("onClick = #menubar > menu > menupopup > menuitem)` should work. Play around and post back what you end up using so others can learn =) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sean Connoly here the correct solution:

The class:

```
package mainPage;


public class MenuAjaxbasedController extends SelectorComposer<Component>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Wire
Center mainContent;

@Wire
Borderlayout mainBorder;

@Wire
Menuitem contatti;

@Wire
Include mainContentInclude;

@Wire
Menubar menubar1;

@Listen("onClick = #menubar1 > menu > menupopup > menuitem")
// @Listen("onClick = #contatti; onClick = #listeDiDistribuzione; onClick = #sottoscrizioni; onClick = #profilo; onClick = #nuovaNewsletter; onClick = #messaggiInviati; onClick = #bozze; onClick = #smtpServers;")
public void change_page(Event e){

    System.out.println(e.getTarget());
    System.out.println(e.getTarget().getId());

    String menuItemId = e.getTarget().getId();
    String locationUri = "";

    switch (menuItemId) {
    case "contatti":  locationUri = "anagraficaContattiMainGrid.zul";
             break;
    case "listeDiDistribuzione":  locationUri = "";
             break;
    case "sottoscrizioni":  locationUri = "";
             break;
    case "profilo":  locationUri = "";
             break;
    case "nuovaNewsletter":  locationUri = "";
             break;
    case "messaggiInviati":  locationUri = "";
             break;
    case "bozze":  locationUri = "";
            break;
    case "smtpServers": locationUri = "";
             break;
    default: locationUri = "anagraficaContattiMainGrid.zul";
             break;
    }

    System.out.println(locationUri);

    Include include = (Include)Selectors.iterable(mainBorder.getPage(), "#mainContentInclude").iterator().next();
    include.setSrc(locationUri);
}

}
```

The index.zul

```
<zk>
<style>.z-menubar-hor, .z-menubar-ver { border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; }
.content {overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll;}</style>

        <borderlayout hflex="1" vflex="1" id="mainBorder" if="${not sessionScope.userCredential.anonymous}">
            <north>
                <include src="topBanner.zul"/>
            </north>
            <west>
                <panel hflex="1" vflex="1" border="normal" title="MENU COMANDI" apply="mainPage.MenuAjaxbasedController">
                    <panelchildren style="padding:5px;">
                        <menubar id="menubar1" orient="vertical" autodrop="true">
                            <menu label="ANAGRAFICA" id="anagrafica">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="contatti" label="CONTATTI" />
                                    <menuitem id="listeDiDistribuzione" label="LISTE DISTRIBUZIONE" />
                                    <menuitem id="sottoscrizioni" label="SOTTOSCRIZIONI" />
                                    <menuitem id="profilo" label="PROFILO" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                            <menu label="MESSAGGI">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="nuovaNewsletter" label="NUOVA NEWSLETTER" />
                                    <menuitem id="messaggiInviati" label="MESSAGGI INVIATI" />
                                    <menuitem id="bozze" label="BOZZE" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                            <menu label="STRUMENTI">
                                <menupopup>
                                    <menuitem id="smtpServers" label="SMTP SERVERS" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                        </menubar>
                    </panelchildren>
                </panel>
            </west>
            <center id="mainContent" autoscroll="true" border="none">
                <include id="mainContentInclude" self="@define(content)" src=""/>
            </center>
            <south>
                <include src="bottomFooter.zul"/>
            </south>
        </borderlayout>
            <div if="${sessionScope.userCredential.anonymous}">
            </div>
</zk>
```